# Plain URL gets flagged as having embbeded credentials by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api

I am working on a website and when making a request fetch to a regular url, JS returns an error related to embbeded credentials which I don't use at all.

The function itself is:

```
var url = 'www.MYURL.com.mialias.net/Week/update__ide.php';
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST"
})
    .then(res=>res.text())
    .then(
        document.getElementById("ide").innerHTML = res;
    })
```

I was expecting no logs and I recieved the log:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Window.fetch: [www.MYDOMAIN.com.mialias.net/Week/update__ide.php](http://www.MYDOMAIN.com.mialias.net/Week/update__ide.php) is an url with embedded credentials.

Comment: It doesn't look like a standard js error. Do you use an external tool like kibana?

Comment: Could it simply be that you are missing the `https://` scheme prefix?

Comment: @Konrad it is a standard error. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request... _"If parsedURL includes credentials, then throw a TypeError"_

Comment: @Phil is it wrong to send credentials in the url?

Comment: @Konrad The Fetch API doesn't allow it

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include a more accurate representation of the URL you're trying to use. Does it have a port specification? Does it include any `:` or `@` characters? Also, what browser (name and version) are you running this on?

Comment: @Phil, yes it was actually just this, for all of you who tried to help, thanks a lot and no, dw, the MYDOMAIN section of the url was just a string name without any kind of `:` or `@`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a guess that your obfuscated URL includes a port specification, eg `:9000`. That or you have an `@` symbol somewhere.

Because you have omitted the URL scheme (ie `https://`), this URL is considered relative with the result looking something like

```
https://example.com/www.MYURL.com.mialias.net:9000/Week/update__ide.php
```

The presence of the `:` matches the URL specification for [*credentials*](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#include-credentials) and as per the [Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request)...

> If *parsedURL* [includes credentials](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#include-credentials), then throw a `TypeError`.

A demonstration (various browsers supply different error messages in their consoles)...

```js
fetch("www.MYURL.com.mialias.net:9000/Week/update__ide.php")
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

The simple solution is to prefix your URL with the correct scheme.

```js
var url = 'https://www.MYURL.com.mialias.net/Week/update__ide.php';
```

Comment: I does not include neither the port specification or the @, it's just a name. It's probably the https:// thing so I'll try to fix it. Thanks for the info!